# setting up apache conf to treat requests from own server

Tags: perl, acl, httpd.conf

I need to apply some rules on HTTP requests using httpd.conf. Here is what I am doing.

1. I am using a perl cgi program to serve the HTTP request. After doing some initial validations I am trying to download the file for the user using `print("Location: /app/download/filename1\n");`
2. I need to control access to this directory /app/download/ such that only this cgi program should be able to download the file, but when the user directly hits the url http://example.com/app/download/filename the download shouldn't be allowed.

Please suggest any technique to achieve this.

Comment: You need disable access to directory and files in Apache config and in script you need open file read it and return content with correctly set HTTP headers

Answer (score 0):

Simply store the files outside of your www root dir, then read the file with your CGI script and return the file content with a correct http header. This is works for light loads.

If your are using Location header to redirect the user request then you won't be able to restrict access to direct file reads. You could try to restrict access with a .httaccess file using referrer url.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "regexp_to_your_web_page" allowit

<Files *>
order allow,deny
allow from env=allowit
deny from all
</Files>
```

See more:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/1233.htm

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limit

Regards,